# how to parse json when it give different type of response

Tags: php, android, json

I am parsing data from JSON in Android, but JSON response is behaving strangely.

If it contains more than one data the response is like this

```
{"e":"701",
    "data":[{"id":"121"},
        {"id":"122"}
    ]
}
```

If it contains only one data the response is like this

```
{"e":"701",
    "data":{"1":{"id":"93"}}
}
```

The code that send JSON response is

```
$r1=mysql_query($sql1,$con);
$count1=mysql_num_rows($r1);
if($count1>0)
{
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($r1)) {
        $data1[$i] = $row1 ;
    }
}    
$c = new Emp();
$c->e = "801";
$c->data =$data1;
echo json_encode($c);
```

How to parse this in one stretch? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you tried so far ??

Comment: Posting some of the code that sends the JSON response would be helpful to answer your question

Comment: @AdiNugroho i have added the code that sends JSON response

Comment: is this code generate the json? This code cannot produce that json format. And where did you define the variable $i?

Answer (score 0):

How about you add this in the while loop ($e will be a variable which in the case above contains 801)

```
$info = array('e' => $e,
'data' => $data1
);
$rows[] = $info;
```

and then out of the while loop you take it out with json as an array which will give you the result you need if I get the question right.

```
echo str_replace("\\","",  json_encode($rows));
```